# Using UPSERT to update conflicting record and inserting a new one afterwards?

Tags: postgresql, unique-constraint, upsert

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to use an `UPSERT` `ON CONSTRAINT` statement in a way that, on conflict, it would update the conflicting record to solve the conflict and afterwards, insert a new record.

Comment: Use `RETURNING` and check the value to see whether the row was inserted with your new values or was updated to resolve the conflict. Then optionally run the second insert.